# Finding the spread of LQD ETF using Price

Tags: python, math, mathematical-optimization, bloomberg, quantitative-finance

I want to know what the calculation is to find LQD Spread using price. The image shown is LQD ETF from Bloomberg, I want to be able to convert 110.24 to 124.82bp in spread. If anybody has a formula or a code, please let me know. Thank you.

[LQD Bloomberg ETF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbk03.png)

Comment: What you are looking at is the effective yield at this price of Corporate Bonds in this particular vehicle ($110.24) compared to an underlying, which in this case seem to be a '33 us gov bonds. The method of calculating that spread is known as "subtraction"; one can't calculate a spread knowing only the spot price for one side of the equation.
This question is most likely going to get closed, because it has nothing to do with programming or an underlying technical question.

Comment: @user2722968 I was able to answer it. Easy question. Yield of LQD compared to the benchmark 10 year treasury is the spread. I answered it both technically and programatically.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do the math.

The G-spread is The YIELD of LQD - the YIELD of the 10 Year government bond... straight forward.

To do this programmatically, just pull the field from Bloomberg

if using excel:

```
=BQL('LQD US EQUITY','YAS_YLD_SPREAD')
```

if using VSCode

```
from xbbg import blp
    
spread = blp.bdp('LQD US EQUITY','YAS_YLD_SPREAD')
spread
```

Edit:

Looks like he wants to convert using only price since price is real time.... Easy stuff.

looking at the code below, just change 'day_open_5' to 'day' if you want the whole day. You can loop through the day and set a schedule if you want. As you can see, this will return the price intra-day

```
from xbbg import blp
import pandas as pd

def get_spread(px):
    # Assuming this function returns a single value based on the input px
    return blp.bdp('lqd us equity','yas_yld_spread',yas_bond_px=f'{px}').values[0][0]

# Load your data
data = blp.bdib('lqd us equity','20231226','day_open_5', ref='IndexUS').droplevel(0, axis=1).reset_index()
data.index = data['index'].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')
data
```

[image]

To convert to spread, just pass it as an override

```
# Apply the function to each cell in the specified columns
for col in ['open', 'high', 'low', 'close']:
    data[col] = data[col].apply(get_spread)
data
```

[image]

as you can see, at the price of 110.15 you get a spread of 136.2583 showing the spread is correctly calculated and converted for every tick.

[image]

Use this method for your realtime chart. I suggest storing the ticks in a sqlite db. ChatGPT can produce the code in less than 1 minute.

Good luck.

Comment: you are the man thank you so much, absolute god